# Is there a way to have an if...unless statement in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code executing currently.

```
For j = 2 To 82 Step 8
    For i = 3 To 70

        y = j + 1
        k = j + 5

    If Not IsError(Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j)) Then

    If Not Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j + 2) = "Safe" Or 
           Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j + 2) = "safe" Then
blahblahblah
```

Now I want to have a line after my last If Not that essentially says "unless column 6 has the word 'F-003'". If that doesn't make sense: I am attempting to omit any lines that include "Safe" UNLESS they also say "F-003", then include it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, but you can easily accomplish this by using well constructed `AND` and `OR`

Comment: Can I combine an "if not" and an "if" using and's and or's?

Comment: yes, and you can use parentheses too...  `if ((x=0 or x=1) and (y=2 and z=4)) or c=1 then`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need the "Not Equal to" (<>) operator. Add one more condition to your Safe, safe if condition.

```
For j = 2 To 82 Step 8
    For i = 3 To 70

        y = j + 1
        k = j + 5

    If Not IsError(Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j)) Then


    If Not Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j + 2) = "Safe" Or 
           Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j + 2) = "safe" And
           Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, 6) <> "F-003" Then
blahblahblah
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make any boolean condition with `if`s. Make something simple. Like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    If 1 = 2 Then
        Debug.Print "1 = 2"
    ElseIf 2 = 4 Then
        Debug.Print "2 = 4"
    ElseIf Not 2 = 5 Then
        Debug.Print "Not 2 = 5"
    End If

End Sub
```

Then edit it until you have something workable.